# Find a time series representation in terms of {Xt} for a process {Yt} whose spectral density is fY (·) = 2f(·)

Tags: time-series, variance, stationarity, spectral-analysis

Suppose you are given a set of data $x_1, \dotsc , x_n$ from a time series process $\{X_t\}$ that has spectral density $f(\cdot)$.  Find a time series representation in terms of $\{X_t\}$ for a process $\{Y_t\}$ whose spectral density is $f_Y (\cdot) = 2 f(\cdot)$. Prove that your representation has this spectral density.